# Azure pipeline ##vso[build.addbuildtag] does not work

Tags: azure, tags, azure-pipelines

I have a problem with adding buildtag to one specific pipeline.

When i use this code with normal string it adds tag successfully:

```
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]TEST_TAG"
  displayName: 'Add TAG to Run'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

but when i use it with variable it throws me an error.

The funniest thing is that same code with variable works fine in another pipeline:

```
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(ChangeNumber)"
  displayName: 'Add TAG to Run'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Error:

```
##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[build.addbuildtag]' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
##[error]Build tag is required.
```

Variable is fine because i "echo" it earlier successfully.
What might be the issue?

Comment: if you add `echo $(ChangeNumber)` before what you get?

Comment: ``echo $(ChangeNumber)`` gives nothing but ``echo "$ChangeNumber"`` gives me actual variable value

Comment: Can you please show us the whole yml files (working/not working) ? how is the variable set at first ? is it supposed shared between stages / jobs ? This might be related to variable scope: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-scopes

Comment: @gipcu so try `echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$ChangeNumber"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that variable was an issue and that it was defined but not passed to another tasks, so the solution is:

```
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Add TAG to Run'
      name: TAG
      inputs:
        targetType: "inline"
        script: |
          ChangeNumber=$(<$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/variables/ChangeNumber.var)
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ChangeNumber;isOutput=true]$ChangeNumber"
          echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$ChangeNumber"
        failOnStderr: true
```